# Plot.ly Double- Axis Formatting Content in R

Tags: r, formatting, data-visualization, plotly

I am having trouble formatting an axis using Plot.ly Double Axis graph. I am trying to get one of the y-axis to contain the '$' symbol in front of the number but I wasn't able to find any code for this. Hope someone can help me figure this out.

```
ay <- list(
tickfont = list(color = "red"),
overlaying = "y",
side = "right"
)

p <- plot_ly(data = df, x = days, y = sales, name = "Sales",type="bar") %>%
add_trace(x = days, y = Sales/Day, name = "Sales/Day", yaxis = "y2") %>%
layout(title = "Double Y Axis", yaxis2 = ay)
```

So in the above code I want to add a '$' symbol to both y axes (Sales and Sales/day).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide a reproducible example, I will use an example from the `plotly` website. You could try:

```
library(plotly)
ay <- list(
  tickfont = list(color = "red"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right"
)
plot_ly(x = 1:3, y = 10*(1:3), name = "slope of 10") %>%
  add_trace(x = 2:4, y = 1:3, name = "slope of 1", yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(title = "Double Y Axis", yaxis2 = ay, yaxis = list(showtickprefix = "all", tickprefix = "$"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the response. Sorry about not adding the code, I added my code to the edited version and to my luck you provided the example from the site as well as the answer to my question. I'll make sure to add code next time around.